# How to write an efficient bash script to find and sort files and directories, extracting dates?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

**Background:** It is a temporary measure to load some test data into a test environment (a Sybase database).

I have a bunch of files I have to import into database daily. These files are organized as such

```
30Aug2011/IMPORT_ME.txt
31Aug2011/IMPORT_ME.txt
...
8Sep2011/IMPORT_ME.txt
9Sep2011/IMPORT_ME.txt
```

After each import I need to run some special sql statement to fix up the date. This is what I did in the main script

```
import_file.sh 20Aug2011/IMPORT_ME.txt
cat rerun_import_file.tmpl | sed -e "s/XXX/8 Aug 2011/g" > rerun_import_files.sql
$ISQL -i rerun_import_files.sql

...
import_file.sh 9Sep2011/IMPORT_ME.txt
cat rerun_import_file.tmpl | sed -e "s/XXX/9 Sep 2011/g" > rerun_import_files.sql
$ISQL -i rerun_import_files.sql
```

So I suppose I can make it better by:

1. find all directories that fit the date pattern
2. sort the dates correctly (very important to the setup)
3. parse the date and set the date according in the sql file

However my bash script-fu is not good enough to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, I missed the sorting part of the question.  To answer that, I propose a different model that's simpler in some ways:

```
ls */IMPORT_ME.txt | cut -d/ -f 1 | date --file=- +%s | sort -n | sed -e 's/^/@/' \
| while read DATE
    do
        FILENAME=`date -d ${DATE} +%-d%b%Y/IMPORT_ME.txt`
        REPLACEMENT=`date -d ${DATE} +%-d %b %Y`
        import_file.sh ${FILENAME}
        cat rerun_import_file.tmpl | sed -e "s/XXX/${REPLACEMENT}/g" > rerun_import_files.sql
        $ISQL -i rerun_import_files.sql
    done
```

The key here is the initial conversion of all of the (filtered for validity) directory names to a sortable time format (in this case Unix 'epoch' time), sorting them, and then converting them back (to two different forms).

If you're working with dates in any more than a purely string manipulation sense, I strongly recommend reading the man page for 'date'.  In fact, read it twice, think hard about it, then read it again.  'date' is an extremely powerful command in its domain.

Oh, and I hope the lesson you have learned from this experience is that you should ALWAYS use ISO format dates (`date -Iseconds` or `date -I` for examples).  ISO format dates sort well as strings using e.g. `sort`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Last remaining piece of puzzle: how can I ensure that the script will iterate these IMPORT_ME.txt files in correct chronological order as suggested by the directory name? I don't wanna see 1Sep comes after 1Aug instead of 2Aug for example.

Comment: Oh.  That makes it simpler in some ways.  See completely changed answer above.

Comment: What are the dependencies in using this solution?  I could not get past the first line on solaris.  My bash -version is 4.1.17 and the only switches allowed on the date command are -a (adjust clock) and -u (universal/GMT).  Even using gdate, there seems to be some sensitivity to white space in the +format of the REPLACEMENT variable.